# Solve differential equation using finite difference method

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix

I am trying to solve a second order differential equation using finite difference method. In the following code I have a function to calculate the first derivative and the second derivative. I am creating a sparse matrix with one column and trying to solve it using `np.linalg`. However, the `f` output is not correctly populated, it's all zeros apart from the boundaries. What am I doing wrong?

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix

# Define the dimensions of the grid
Lx = 2   # Length of the grid in the x-direction
Nx = 11    # Number of grid points in the x-direction

fa = 2
fb = 0.2

I = np.eye(Nx)

def compute_derivatives(Nx, dx):
    # Compute grid spacing
    x = np.linspace(0, Lx, Nx)
    dx = Lx/(Nx-1)

    # Initialize arrays for first and second order derivatives
    DX = np.zeros(Nx)
    DX2 = np.zeros(Nx)

    # Compute first and second order derivatives using central differences
    for i in range(1, Nx-1):
        DX[i] = (x[i+1] - x[i-1]) / (2*dx)
        DX2[i] = (x[i+1] - 2*x[i] + x[i-1]) / (dx**2)

    return DX, DX2

DX,DX2 = compute_derivatives(Nx,Lx)

A = DX2 + 5*DX + 6*I
b = csc_matrix((Nx, 1)).toarray()
A[[0, Nx-1], :] = 0
A[0,0]=1
A[Nx-1,Nx-1] = 1
b[0] = fa
b[-1] = fb

f = np.linalg.solve(A, np.asarray(np.array(b), dtype=float))
print(f)
```

Comment: Your derivatives should be in terms of the function values, not the coordinate values (schematically, `dydt = (y[i+1] - y[i-1]) / (2*dx)`). You should end up with a (sparse) tridiagonal matrix `A`. Using a sparse matrix for `b` doesn't make much sense, as it's just an ordinary vector.

Comment: @yut23 can you give me the example of the function using `y` to calculate the derivative? The notes I am referring computed the derivatives the way I have in my code. However, as you said my `A` matrix is not tridiagonal. The diagonals are ok, but outside the diagonal it should be `0`.

Comment: What you have is the correct way to calculate the derivative of some data with finite differences, but you actually want to construct the system of equations you get when you apply the finite difference formulas to the derivatives in the ODE. Here's a good reference I found: https://pythonnumericalmethods.berkeley.edu/notebooks/chapter23.03-Finite-Difference-Method.html. Your existing code gives `DX = 1` and `DX2 = 0` (excluding the edges), as expected for `d(x)/dx` and `d^2(x)/dx^2`.